# How to add a Collider for the Mesh from script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a function that draws `Mesh`.

It is drawn on the **XZ** plane and **Y** is a constant value

I am trying to add `Collider` inside the function but I am having a problem. I can't catch the correct shape.

I will add that none of the default Collider works properly

```
GameObject DrawMesh2D(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint, float width, string name)
{
    List<Vector2> vertices2D = new List<Vector2>();
    List<Vector3> vertices3D = new List<Vector3>();

    GameObject polygon = new GameObject();
    polygon.name = name;

    var v = endPoint - startPoint;
    var s = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(v, Vector3.up));
    var P1 = startPoint + s * width / 2;
    var P2 = startPoint - s * width / 2;
    var P3 = endPoint - s * width / 2;
    var P4 = endPoint + s * width / 2;

    vertices3D.Add(P1);
    vertices3D.Add(P2);
    vertices3D.Add(P3);
    vertices3D.Add(P4);

    vertices2D.Add(new Vector2(P1.x, P1.z));
    vertices2D.Add(new Vector2(P2.x, P2.z));
    vertices2D.Add(new Vector2(P3.x, P3.z));
    vertices2D.Add(new Vector2(P4.x, P4.z));

    var triangulator = new Triangulator(vertices2D.ToArray());
    var indices = triangulator.Triangulate();

    var mesh = new Mesh
    {
        vertices = vertices3D.ToArray(),
        triangles = indices
    };

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();

    var meshRenderer = polygon.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

    var filter = polygon.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    filter.mesh = mesh;

    polygon.transform.parent = area2D.transform;

    var polygonCollider = polygon.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();

    polygonCollider.pathCount = 4;
    polygonCollider.SetPath(0, new Vector2[] { new Vector2(P1.x, P1.z), new Vector2(P2.x, P2.z) });
    polygonCollider.SetPath(1, new Vector2[] { new Vector2(P2.x, P2.z), new Vector2(P3.x, P3.z) });
    polygonCollider.SetPath(2, new Vector2[] { new Vector2(P3.x, P3.z), new Vector2(P4.x, P4.z) });
    polygonCollider.SetPath(3, new Vector2[] { new Vector2(P4.x, P4.z), new Vector2(P1.x, P1.z) });

    return polygon;
}
```

Comment: `none of the default Collider works properly` what exactly does that mean? What exactly is the problem with the solution you are using currently? Why not simply set `polygonCollider.points = vertices2D.ToArray();` ?

Comment: Actually your case looks like simply creating a 2D quad and scale it accordingly would be way easier? Rotate it accordingly , add a `BoxCollider2D` and done, right?